# How to Run a jQuery Script Before Page Start to Load

Tags: jquery, wordpress, swap

everyone. Got WORDPRESS + DIVI THEME.

I wrote a script to SWAP LOGOS ON SCROLL. Here it is:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
 $(document).scroll(function() {
   if($('#main-header').hasClass('et-fixed-header')) {
      $('#logo').attr('src','SECOND_LOGO_IMAGE');
   }
   else {
      $('#logo').attr('src','FIRST_LOGO_IMAGE');
   }
 });
});
</script>
```

It works! And i'm quite happy about it.

So i want to load it before the page starts to load to prevent FIRST_LOGO_IMAGE shows on page then it was reloaded in the middle of site.

Everytime the page was reloaded i got FIRST_LOGO_IMAGE before start to scroll.

Probably, i don't need to change logos ON SCROLL, i just need them to swap, then the #main-header change class to #et-fixed-header and back.

Comment: Do you mean you want to keep the picture showing in `$('#logo')` when the page is refreshed?

Comment: Have you tried: $(window).load(function() { in place of $(document).scroll(function() {

Answer (score 0):

I would say you would need to add a CSS rule like:

```
.et-fixed-header {
background: url(new-image-url); }
```

From what I see that fixed class is added only if you scroll down a page, so even if you load a page in the middle, the class should be attached and, with it, your new header once setup in CSS.